# Google API Reading .p12 key in python 3

Tags: python, encoding, google-api, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to port some code from Python 2 to 3, but it's throwing a `UnicodeDecodeError` when it reads the Google API .p12 service key.

```
with open('service_key.p12', 'r') as f:
    private_key = f.read()
```

Here is the error

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 1: invalid start byte`

This code works fine in python 2.7, it breaks with python 3.4 
Also I have `pyOpenSSL==0.14` installed.

Answer (score 5):

In python 3 you have to use the 'b' flag as well for opening binary files:

```
with open('service_key.p12', 'rb') as f:
    private_key = f.read()
```

As described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o), Binary I/O will not do character encoding/decoding. You get the UnicodeDecodeError because you used Text I/O, which tries to decode the data as UTF-8, but your data is not valid UTF-8.